# matplotlib - runtime adding multiple lines without knowing in advance

Tags: python, pointers, reference, matplotlib

I am trying to add multiple lines on a single figure without knowing the number of lines in advance. I currently have a class that has x and y values that are used for the line within a single session.

I am unsure how to add a new line for each new session within the same figure. Creating that association to be specific.

Within my main function I have the following code.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line,= plt.figure().plot(0,0)
```

In my session class. I have the following code.

```
class Session:
x = []
y = []
# I think I should add a line here... but I am not sure 
# how to make this association to the main.
```

For each session, it stores the x and y values and I can retrieve those values through methods. That part is easy but associating each line to the same graph is what I am having trouble at. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: You can call `.plot()` multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I also would like to add colors and styles to easily identify the different lines.

Comment: Before, I tried setting line to a figure which turned out creating a new figure each time there was a new session and no line was appearing on each of them. (Which is totally what I do not want. I want all the lines in one figure)

Currently I am trying to implement the axis into the class and hoping that I can associate it that way.

Comment: @freedom that's b/c you're calling `plt.figure().plot()`. The `figure` portion is making a new figure. use `ax.plot(...)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `.plot()` multiple times. I added an example of how to change the line color. I will leave the styling to you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

colors = ('b','g','r','c','m','y','k','w',)
sessions = (sess1, sess2, sess3)
for sess, color in zip(sessions, colors):
    ax.plot(sess.x, sess.y, color=color)
```

---

If you want to use, and/or re-use, a specific set of colors for all of your lines [`itertools.cycle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) makes short work of it:

```
import itertools as it

colors = ('b','g','r',)
sessions = (sess1, sess2, sess3, sess4, sess5, sess6)
for sess, color in zip(sessions, it.cycle(colors)):
    ax.plot(sess.x, sess.y, color=color)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But, how is the color being used in the for loop?